# Can I create omnet++ cc source file for INET module StandaredHost or any module

Tags: omnet++, inet

I don't know how this question will sound like but I'm this is the best place to ask anything about science.

I am trying to create a cc omnet++ source file for INET modues. Like we do in simple module, we simple inherit that class with cSimpleModule and then we give implementation of Initialize and handleMessage methods. I tried creating a cc source file and then inherit it by StandaredHost and declared the both methods initialize and handleMessge, but it is not working.

I want to know the proper way of doing so.

What I want to achieve is that I want to make a source file for each module when I can probe message, schedule it, apply other queuing algorithms like we do simple modules.

Answer (score 3):

`StandardHost` from `INET` is a [compound module](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:compound-modules). Usually compound module includes [simple modules](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:simple-modules). In `OMNeT++` behavior is defined *only* for simple modules. So one cannot define a C++ classes for a compound module.

Comment: Not 100% true, one can define C++ code for a compound module, the manual states: `Although the C++ class for a compound module can be overridden with the @class property, this is a feature that should probably never be used. Encapsulate the code into a simple module, and add it as a submodule.`
or
`The user defines simple module types by subclassing cSimpleModule. Compound modules are instantiated with cModule, although the user can override it with @class in the NED file, and can even use a simple module C++ class (i.e. one derived from cSimpleModule) for a compound module.`

Comment: @MichaelKirsche: that is true what you have written. However, C++ class of compound module could not send messages nor process incoming messages. Only `cSimpleModule` has implemented `handleMessage()` as well as is able to send a message.

Comment: absolutely true Jerzy, behavior should go into the simple modules. Like the manual states, better encapsulate the code into a simple module and add it into a submodule.