# A new module that inherit from AdhocHost in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, adhoc, inet

I need a new module that inherit from `AdhocHost`. Friends asked  before [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893578/can-i-create-omnet-cc-source-file-for-inet-module-standaredhost-or-any-module), and Mr [Jerzy D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653172/jerzy-d) answered that:

> In OMNeT++ behavior is defined only for simple modules. So one cannot
>   define a C++ classes for a compound module.

but the manual states:

> Although the C++ class for a compound module can be overridden with
>   the @class property, this is a feature that should probably never be
>   used. Encapsulate the code into a simple module, and add it as a
>   submodule.

How can I create this module? It is not logical to create a `cSimpleModule` module from scratch because I wanna use predefined `AdhocHost` parameters,method,... and also my new define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, in `OMNeT++` there is the possibility to define a class for compound module. My answer you have mentioned was not 100% correct.

---

To create a new module that inherits from `AdhocHost` and has own class one should do at least:

1. In `inet4\src\inet\node\inet` create a new file `AdhocHostExtended.ned`:

   ```
   package inet.node.inet;
   import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;

   module AdhocHostExtended extends AdhocHost {
       @class(AdhocHostExtended);
       int par1;
       double par2;
   }
   ```
2. In the same directory create `AdhocHostExtended.h`:

   ```
   #ifndef __INET4_ADHOCHOSTEXTENDED_H_
   #define __INET4_ADHOCHOSTEXTENDED_H_

   #include <omnetpp.h>
   using namespace omnetpp;

   namespace inet {

   class AdhocHostExtended : public cModule  {
     protected:
       virtual int numInitStages() const override { return NUM_INIT_STAGES; }
       virtual void initialize(int stage) override;
       virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
   };

   } //namespace
   #endif
   ```
3. In the same directory create `AdhocHostExtended.cc`:

   ```
   #include "AdhocHostExtended.h"
   namespace inet {

   Define_Module(AdhocHostExtended);

   void AdhocHostExtended::initialize(int stage) {
     // an example of reading new parameter in the first stage
     if (stage == INITSTAGE_LOCAL) {
        EV << "par1 = " << par("par1").intValue() << endl;
     }
     // your code
   }

   void AdhocHostExtended::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
        // your code
   }      

   } //namespace
   ```

Take care of using a proper stage inside `initialize()`. Stages are defined in `/inet4/src/inet/common/InitStages.h`

Comment: Although the C++ class for a compound module can be overridden with the @class property, this is a feature that should probably never be used. Encapsulate the code into a simple module, and add it as a submodule.

Comment: In file AdhocHostExtended.cc, the function "void AdhocHostExtended::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)" never is called. The other functions were not tested.