# Using of Adhochost nodes instead of Omnet++ example

Tags: omnet++

In Inet of Omnet++, developers proposed a sample as the following URL:
https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp4/tictoc-tutorial/classTxc13.html

If I need to replace Adhochost nodes instead of Tcx13, I encounter many problems like these items:

```
1.handlemessage function does not work normally
2.writing to scalar files and signals
```

I want to have my defined messages like the example(message13).
What is the best approach.

Comment: Could you provide [mcve] as well as explain what do you mean by _handlemessage function does not work normally_?

Comment: The point is that Tx13 inherits from class cSimpleModule, not related class AdhocHost of Inet, so the function handlemessage does not work normally. I want to Tx13 inherites AdhocHost related class instead of cSimpleModule class. Similar link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893578/can-i-create-omnet-cc-source-file-for-inet-module-standaredhost-or-any-module?noredirect=1&lq=1)